# CSS: Want text to be in the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Person Name </label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Person Name ">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Event Title </label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Person Name ">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Person Name** and **Event Title**, both have same number of characters that is **11**. But still when I see in my webpage. I get **Person Name** , getting in two lines.

Here is the image for the same.

[image: Person Name]
[image: Event Title]

Thank You.

Comment: Try to adjust the col-lg-2 to col-lg-3 to have more width. so that it wont have 2 lines.

Comment: Or use `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: Post your css code

Comment: @PrasathV... I have used Bootstrap API...

Comment: @skobaljic... it worked.. Thank You.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Update like this :

```
<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Person Name </label>
<div class="col-lg-9">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. but i have to use **col-lg-2** and **col-lg-10**. Because for text box i have to increase its width.

Comment: use white-space: nowrap

Answer (score 0):

use **form-horizontal** class to look good in all devices and text in same line.

**Large devices**  : label and input are in one line.

**Small devices (mobile)** : label comes top of input. and it looks good.

try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Person Name" >Person Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Person Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Event Title">Event Title:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Person Name">
      </div>
    </div>
         </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had used in my previous task. but There is a need for the same line of text and input field. that's why i m using this one

Answer (score 0):

**Just add below code in your css**

> .control-label{white-space: nowrap;}